# React Native WebView not showing the full height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webview

I am trying to render the full height of the website using the web view, it is not working as expected. A small portion of the bottom is getting cut off. It's happening because of the paddingHorizontal in the main view. I am able to see the full website if I remove that padding. How do I solve this issue, I cannot delete that padding.

```
return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{}}>
      <TopBar navigation={navigation} isHome={true} />
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{}}>
        <Text> dsdsdsdsddss </Text>
        <View style={{height:200}}></View>
        <View style={styles.mainview}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <WebView
              contentInset={{bottom: 20}}
              bounces={false}
              style={{height: webViewHeight}}
              onMessage={onWebViewMessage}
              scrollEnabled={false}
              source={{
                uri: url,
              }}
              onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
              injectedJavaScript={`
        const height = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight);
        window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(height.toString());
      `}></WebView>
     
          </View>
          <View style={{height:200, backgroundColor:"red"}}></View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainview: {
    paddingHorizontal: 16, //This padding is causing the issue
    paddingVertical: 24,
    flex: 1,
  },
  container: {
    backgroundColor: COLORS.white,
    borderRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5,
    shadowColor: COLORS.black,
    shadowOffset: {
      height: 4,
      width: 0,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.07,
    shadowRadius: 15,
  },
});
```

Comment: what is the value of webViewHeight ? you can try decreasing it or removing bottomInset on webview or using margin instead of padding

Comment: tried all, height of the web view is scrollHeight calculated by injecting javascript in the web page. I have tried removing the bottonInset, using margin instead of padding, but nothing is working.